# Where do I submit the token after getting the user's payment data with Stripe's React PaymentElement?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, payment

When using Stripe with ReactJS, I am confused about where to submit the payment tokens after the user has filled out their credit card info.  I have this payment container that gets a peyment intent from my server ...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    OrderService.createPaymentIntent(cart)
      .then((paymentIntent) => {
        setOrderTotal(paymentIntent.orderTotal);
        setOptions({ ...options, clientSecret: paymentIntent.clientSecret });
        setOrderTotal(paymentIntent.orderTotal);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching profile:", error);
      });
  }, []);
    ...          {options?.clientSecret && (
            <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
              <CheckoutForm />
            </Elements>

      )}
```

and below I have my CheckoutForm.tsx file.  However, I'm confused about where to submit the  data obtained from the "createToken" call.  Does this need to be submitted to my server to in turn submit to stripe or should this be submitted directly to stripe?

```
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
    ...

  const handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    const cardElement = elements?.getElement("card");

    stripe
      ?.createToken(cardElement) 
      .then((payload) => console.log("[token]", payload)); 
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement />
      <button disabled={!stripe}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

If this is submitted directly to stripe, how do I record on my server what happened with this particular order?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you'd like want to submit the data directly to Stripe. Your server should implement [Stripe webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) in order to capture the processed payment data and subsequently perform any necessary back-end actions accordingly.

Comment: Would the webhook live on my server, take the token generated by the <PaymentElement />, and submit that to Stripe?  And then I'd capture the response, do something with it, and then report back to the client?

Answer (score 1):

From the code snipped you shared, it looks like you're using [Card Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/get_element#elements_get_element-type) and Token which are their legacy approach and you should instead use [Payment Elements](https://%20https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-card-element-comparison).

Just a bit more context on what Payment Elements does. The Payment Element offers an embedded UI component for you to accept many Payment Methods securely with one integration. Depending on where your customer is, it dynamically sorts the Payment Method to optimize conversion, adjusts input fields automatically for different Payment Methods, validates inputs to reduce friction for card payments. In the future, if you decide to add other payment methods, you can just enable them in your Dashboard to start supporting them on your Checkout page. Here is their [integration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?platform=web&client=react) that you can use as a guidance.

After the customer provides payment method details, you can confirm the Payment on the client-side. Is there are any immediate errors, Stripe.js returns that error. If there is not, you can listen to wehbook events to [handle post payment actions](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart#handle-immediate-errors).

Comment: In the code example I provided, I'm using "<PaymentElement />".  That is the current (i.e. non-legacy) approach, no?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code provided, which seems taken from the Stripe documentations, you have reached the final step of the integration for  "Creating an account" or "Create a person". That means that after receiving the token, you are now suppose to send it to your backend as a final step in order to create an account and/or a person on your backend using Stripe. Check this link for more details: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens

BUT this is useful only for cases where you need tokens to ensure that personally identifiable information (PII) doesn’t reach your servers.

What you'd rather do to confirm the PaymentIntent is to use `stripe.confirmCardPayment`. Check the Stripe.js docs on: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment.

An example of implementing it might be the following code:

```
async function submitOrder(data) {
        setLoading(true);
        const { nameOnCard, saveAddress, ...shippingAddress } = data;
        if (!stripe || !elements || !clientSecret) {
            // Stripe.js hasn't yet loaded.
            // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
            return;
        } // Stripe is not ready
        try {
            const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement); // CardNumberElement is imported from @stripe/react-stripe-js as well
            const paymentResult = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: cardElement,
                    billing_details: {
                        name: nameOnCard, // sending additional properties
                    },
                },
            });
            console.log(paymentResult); // you can visualize the result in the console

            if (paymentResult.paymentIntent?.status === "succeeded") {
                // create the order in the back-end                
                setPaymentSucceeded(true); // use as many flags as you want
                setPaymentMessage("Thank you - we have received your payment");
                setLoading(false);
            } else {
                setPaymentMessage(paymentResult.error?.message || "Payment failed");
                setPaymentSucceeded(false);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }
```

After that, as said in the other answer by [@pgs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18347141/pgs): "If there are any errors, Stripe.js returns that error. If there is not, you can listen to webhook events to handle post payment actions."

I hope that helps at least a bit.

Comment: You've linked to Account Tokens which are irrelevant here. The right guide to follow here is https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?platform=web&type=payment#create-intent which recommends creating a PaymentMethod first (not a Token), making a request to your server to create a PaymentIntent and obtain its client_secret and then confirm that on your frontend using Stripe.js's `confirmPayment()` function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I'm not understanding the "you can listen to webhook events to handle post payment actions" statement.  Where is this webhook set up and what is it doing?  THe person who posted that comment also didni't answer my question asking for details on this point.

Comment: To answer this part of the question, I have to add that for the webhook (receiving Stripe events, like for instance informing you when the payment is done), you must create a post request endpoint fn on your BE (anonymous access, because Stripe won't work either). Inside you can modify a field of your choice, providing you this additional information for each order/payment intent. On the FE part you check this field to get this info wherever needed. After creating it (following the docs for your backend type),  you manage and register it in your Stripe's Dashboard -> Developer -> Webhooks.

Comment: I'm almost there -- in your code example, you created a FE submitOrder call so when would the FE invoke the BE webhook I have created?  Would it be called after the submitOrder call completes successfully?  Also, what information am I sending to this BE webhook?

Comment: Yes, after you submit the order with status "succeeded", it is now up to Stripe to post to your webhook endpoint whenever the desired event is triggered (you manage which event, while registering the webhook). In the moment it is done,  the code on your BE should extract the needed info from the request that Stripe is sending, you access the StripeEvent object, and if succeeded, you change the status of your corresponding order (with same PaymentIntentId). Save this status in your database, so the next time you request this order on your FE, you see that the payment is done, or whatever it is.

Comment: Regarding "whenever the desired event is triggered," I want to know when my payment has completed, so what event am I expecting to receive from Stripe?  Do I need to register my webhook with the Stripe or is it just a callback I have setup on my backend that Stripe invokes?

Comment: payment has completed - try with "charge succeeded". So the event is Charge.
it is a callback set up on backend that Stripe invokes but you have to register it on Stripe's Dashboard -> Developer -> Webhooks as I told you above.